# How to create ObjectId in Mongoose 4.0.x from Hex string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

mongoose.mongo.Types.ObjectId does not have fromString or fromHexString functions.
It seems that new mongoose.mongo.Types.ObjectId(hexString) does not create an object id either.

```
var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(hexString);
db.Record.find({_id:id }, function (err, campaign){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    callback(campaign);
});
```

Comment: And what's `hexString`? ObjectId generally accepts hexadecimal strings ?

Comment: I would venture to guess that your problem isn't that `campaign` is null, but rather that it's returning an array and you're trying to access the properties of the document against the array, not a single document. Change your query to use `findById`. If that's not the case, what's the value of `id` before the query is executed?

Comment: returns empty array. Tired find one and findById still no success.

Comment: @adeneo - hex string: '553f8a4286f5c759f36f8e5b'

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the method you're looking for. The `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` class has a static function called `createFromHexString`, which returns an instance of an `ObjectId`.

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(hexString);
db.Record.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, campaign){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    callback(campaign);
});
```